# Using database and managing users on .net mvc web application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a website that maintain users (using the mvc5 Identity feature) and some more data. I'm using .net mvc and I'm quite new to this.

In my website if you are not logged in you are displayed with some data and if you are logged in you are displayed with the same data and also some user data.

my connection string is as follows

```
<add name="CoursesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.Model1.csdl|res://*/DAL.Model1.ssdl|res://*/DAL.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Courses.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=false&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

but whenever I launch the website I get this error

```
"Cannot open database [location of the .mdf file] requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user [some user]."
```

Comment: The error indicates that the user the application is running as doesn't have permission to connect to the SQL Server LocalDb instance.  Your connection string shows that this is Database First Entity framework, so you are connecting to an existing database.  Is this database configured to allow Windows Authentication, and is the user account that mvc runs as given access to the database?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm sorry but I'm quite new to this features.
how can I check the configurations?

Comment: Typically this is done using sql server management studio to grant permissions.  When I look at your connection string I'm actually a little confused by it.  It really looks like a Database First connection string, but typically these point to full sql servers, not LocalDb.  I've never actually seen a LocalDb authentication fail, so it may be some kind of filesystem permission check that needs to be fixed via permission in explorer.

Comment: @BradleyUffner so what can I do to in order to try and fix that?

Comment: Make sure that the app-pool user has access to the file on disk, and that the database is configured (through management studio) to allow that user to connect to the database and has a role that allows for editing data.  Sorry, I don't have time right now to do step-by-step trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write this string by your self ?

connection string looks like this :

```
<add name="NameofString" connectionString=" server=NameofServer ; database=databaseName ; integrated-security=SSPI" providerName="SqlClient"/>
```

example :

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DBContext" connectionString="server = .\SQLEXPRESS ; database = MVCAppDB2 ; integrated security = SSPI " providerName="SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

connection string which you are showing is auto-generated according to me.

Comment: the string is auto-generated indeed